# Representatives of Chern classes for compact symplectic manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

It is well-known that the curvature forms of the (complexified) Levi-Civita connection can be used to provide explicit representatives for Chern classes of compact Kähler manifolds. This is not true for symplectic manifolds. So my question is, for a general compact symplectic manifold, does there exist any method to produce explicit closed forms to represent Chern classes.

Thanks in advances!

Comment: The Chern classes are always the deRham classes of the Chern forms, for any complex vector bundle with connection on any real manifold.

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes. We can use the Chern connection to obtain representatives for Chern classes of compex vector bundle. But what I want to know is the case for symplectic manifolds, whose tangent bundles are almost complex.

Comment: An almost complex structure makes the tangent bundle a complex vector bundle (perhaps not holomorphic). So you use the usual Chern forms.

Comment: You do not need Chern connection (which is indeed defined only for holomorphic vector bundles), any U(n)-connection will work.

Comment: You don't even need a $U(n)$-connection. Any $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$-connection will work.

Comment: @BenMcKay What I mean is if there exists a canonical method (for example, the Levi-Civita connection on Kahler manifold) to produce such representatives.

Comment: The only differential forms on a symplectic manifold invariant under all symplectomorphism are the constant multiples of powers of the symplectic form. Looking at Kaehler examples, you can see that there are compact symplectic manifolds which have Chern classes not represented by their symplectic form or its multiples. Therefore there is no symplectomorphism invariant expression for Chern forms to represent Chern classes. You need to pick extra structure. If your extra structure gives  a connection on the associated $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$-bundle, you can use the usual Chern forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symplectic manifolds equipped with an adapted  almost complex structure are also called almost-Kahler manifolds.    There are many connections on the tangent bundle compatible with the metric    induced by the symplectic  form and the almost complex structure. Each one of them is uniquely determined by its torsion.

According to Paul Gauduchon, the Chern connection on an almost Kahler manifold  is the  connection  compatible with the metric and whose torsion is equal to the Nijenhuis tensor $N$.  It is the one with the smallest torsion amongst all the connections compatible  with both the metric  and the almost complex structure and it is precisely the connection used by Taubes in his work on Seiberg-Witten equations on symplectic $4$-manifolds.   For more details and references [see  Section 1.4.1 of these notes.](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/swnotes.pdf)

Obviously in the case, in the case of Kahler manifolds, the Nijenhuis tensor is zero and the Chern connection coincides with the Levi--Civita connection.